# How can I remove system apps on my amazon fire 7 9th gen tablet using adb commands?

Tags: adb, uninstallation, bloatware

I'm tired of bloatware on my amazon fire 7 tablet (9th gen)

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3922213

Answer (score 1):

## 1. Find out the package names

In order to uninstall the apps, you need their package names. Within an `adb shell`, execute:

```
pm list packages
```

Take note of all the package names that you want to uninstall. (PLEASE be careful. **DO a backup first.** Many if not all sources say it's oh so easy to re-install apps because you don't really fully delete them and only uninstall them for the current user but I did have issues with re-installing it on some devices in the past! Also removing crucial system applications can cause bootloops.)

## 2. Uninstall the package

```
pm uninstall -k --user 0 PACKAGE
```

Replace `PACKAGE` with the name of the package (e.g. `com.confetti.app`).
`-k` is to `keep the data and cache directories around after package removal`, this might be neccessary without root. It worked without it on an LG device for me in the past though.
`--user 0` uninstalls the app just for the current user, so basically the app is still there, but since uninstalled for the main user, it won't bother you in any kind of way. Without root or RW access to the system partition, this is your best bet.

**Done.**

---

**Alternative method (requires a recovery with RW access to the `/system` partition):**

On some devices you can use a custom recovery to do this, slightly more efficiently, aswell. You won't need root within the phone (e.g. no superuser app.) but you will need a custom recovery and the ability to mount the `/system` partition as `RW`. Then you can use this, within an `adb shell` in recovery:

```
mount /system
ls /system/app
```

This will list your system apps. Take note of what you want to delete. For example if you want to delete `confetti.apk`, run this command:

```
rm /system/app/confetti.apk
```

Do this command for every app you want to remove, then restart your device.

---

## In any case: **BACKUP FIRST**